# Searching web and displaying the results in a native app

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have been working on a searching app some time now and yesterday I encountered a problem. I could say that my app is something like those hotels searching apps. I was browsing the internet and I couldn't find a solid tutorial for "web data processing" or what is it called.

So my problem is, how do I get the results or data to my app, when user press the search button? Let's say I want to search some hotels in some location, what's the concept usually used for getting the results to my app and display it in a TableView?

Does anyone now how to do it, I don't need a step by step guide :) just the basic concept? I'll take every help here, I'm lost :-/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if I got you right, but you could do it like this. (just a concept, not a tutorial)

You could use a Google Maps API, not sure which one but the Places API looks like it is the best for you - https://developers.google.com/places/ .

Then just send a request, receive and process a JSON response of the server and show the result in your app.

It shouldn't be very hard to implement, just be sure to read through the documentation :)

Answer (score 0):

Google Map API is the thing which you find. You can use xml file or database to store the place details (latitude and longitude, address etc.). While searching you can read the xml or database. If you like jQuery you can use auto complete for make easy this searching process :D